# Least absolute deviation minimization by derivative.

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, optimization

$Q=\sum_{i=1}^{N} |y_i-\rho|$

I know that $dQ/d\rho=0$ implies to $\rho=median\{y_1,...y_N\}$ but I dont even know why this minimizes $Q$ since $d^2Q/d\rho^2=0$ and isn't >0.

Look at:

$\displaystyle\frac{dQ}{d\rho}=-\sum_{i=1}^{N}sign(y_i-\rho) $

remember $sign(x)=\displaystyle\frac{x}{|x|}=\frac{|x|}{x}$

$\displaystyle\frac{dQ}{d\rho}=-\sum_{i=1}^{N}\frac{(y_i-\rho)}{|y_i-\rho|} $

$\displaystyle\frac{d^2Q}{d\rho^2}=-\sum_{i=1}^{N}\frac{-|y_i-\rho|+sign(y_i-\rho)(y_i-\rho)}{(y_i-\rho)^2}$

$\displaystyle\frac{d^2Q}{d\rho^2}=-\sum_{i=1}^{N}\frac{-|y_i-\rho|+\displaystyle\frac{|y_i-\rho|}{(y_i-\rho)}(y_i-\rho)}{(y_i-\rho)^2}$

$\displaystyle\frac{d^2Q}{d\rho^2}=-\sum_{i=1}^{N}\frac{-|y_i-\rho|+\displaystyle{|y_i-\rho|}}{(y_i-\rho)^2}=0$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The function $\rho \mapsto \sum_i |y_i - \rho|$ is not differentiable at $y_1, \ldots, y_N$, so there will be some caveats to using derivatives to reason about minimizers.

I haven't checked your calculations, but it is not surprising that your computation leads to a zero second derivative. The original function $\sum_i |y_i - \rho|$ is a piecewise linear function in $\rho$ with "knots" at $y_1, \ldots, y_N$. Your derivative computations should be valid for values of $\rho$ that aren't at the knots; because the function is linear at each segment, you'll get a zero second derivative there. However, this does not tell you immediately about the function globally because of the non-differentiability at the knots. [There are things called [subderivatives](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Subderivative) that generalize the idea of derivatives to handle these situations, but it's not necessary to go into that here.]

If you want to argue that the critical point is a minimizer, try showing that the first derivative is nonnegative to the right of the critical point, and nonpositive to the left of the critical point.

---

Let $f(\rho) = \sum_i |y_i - \rho|$.

Claim: if $\rho^*$ is a median of $y_1, \ldots, y_N$, then $f(\rho^*) \le f(\rho)$ for any $\rho$.

For simplicity I assume $y_1 < \cdots < y_N$. For cases where some of the $y_i$ are the same, the argument below can be modified to handle it.

It suffices to show that $f(\rho) \le f(\rho')$ for $\rho^* \le \rho \le \rho'$, and that $f(\rho') \ge f(\rho)$ for $\rho' \le \rho \le \rho^*$.

Show that $f$ is a piecewise linear function with knots at $y_1 \le \cdots \le y_N$ and slopes $-N, -(N-2), -(N-4), \ldots, N-4, N-2, N$. (You've basically already done this in your computation of $dQ/d\rho$.) Once you've done this, you've shown that $f$ has a "jagged U" shape, so there are global minimizers.

- When $N$ is even, there is a segment of slope $0$ in the middle, between $y_{N/2}$ and $y_{N/2 + 1}$. Any point on this segment serves as a median, and you can see from the shape of $f$ that these are all minimizers.
- When $N$ is odd, the two segments between $y_{(N-1)/2}, y_{(N+1)/2}, y_{(N+3)/2}$ have slopes $-1$ and $1$. This middle point $y_{(N+1)/2}$ is the median and can be seen to be the minimizer due to the shape of $f$.

Again, I've assumed the $y_1, \ldots, y_N$ are unique; you can modify this argument to handle the more general case when some values are repeated.

Comment: Why it is not differentiable at $\rho=median\{y_1,...,y_N \}$? (I think that you've meant that rather $y_1,...,y_N$) since $\rho$ is real-valuated and median as well.

Comment: @DaviAmérico I mean that the function is not differentiable at the $N$ points $y_1, \ldots, y_N$. I've edited to be clearer.

Comment: Let $N$ be odd number then the median is some $y_k$ but Second derivative isn't deffined at $y_k$ since $k \in {1,...,N}$. How can i check it to $N$ even?

Comment: @DaviAmérico See my update

Comment: Why any point in $[y_{N/2},y_{N/2+1}] $ is median? if $N$ is even the median is unique determinate by $(y_{N/2}+y_{N/2+1})/2$

Comment: @DaviAmérico Sorry, I'm using a more general definition of the median that is common in probability. You can use your definition (mean of the two middle elements) if you wish.

Comment: I've found out a more trivial proof to it (I guess the proof below seems to sub-gradients) 

Let $a=median-\epsilon$ where $\epsilon>0$ so:

$dQ(a)/d\rho<0$ 'cause We've got more negative signals than positive then the final sign will be positive but is there (-1) on it then $dQ(a)/d\rho<0$

.The same way to $\epsilon<0$